# how to delete multiple records with one query

Tags: php, mysql

i would like to delete multiple records with one query using mysql and php instead of using any loops.

```
$query = "DELETE FROM countries c WHERE c.id = 8";
```

what is the syntax for that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$query = "DELETE FROM countries c WHERE c.id in(4,5,6,7,8,89,9, ....)";


$query = "DELETE FROM countries c WHERE c.id > 5  and c.id < 25";
```

Comment: i would like to know which is the better way for deleting the records. all at once using the above code or using loops?

Comment: all at once is the best, and fastest, both for sql and php

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use

```
$query = "DELETE FROM countries c WHERE c.id = 8 OR c.id = 9 OR c.id = 10";
```

Didn't test this code but I think it should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you know all of the id's you can say "WHERE c.id in (8,9,10)"